# How to create an interactive graph network of resources, diseases, triggers and treatments using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, graph, sigma.js

I am having a difficult time creating a network of resources (such as pubmed articles, webpages, forum threads, or lawsuits), diseases, triggers and treatments.

I have taken a look at numerous examples, but they all use Node.js. Why is node.js required when all I am looking for is front-end interactivity?

Please see the attached image for exactly what I am looking for. Any recommendations or insights would be greatly appreciated. I am leaning towards sigma.js or d3.js, but I think my idea is simple enough that it shouldn't require server side logic, but so many existing interactive examples dictate that node.js is required?

Can I use Wordpress for this instead of Node.js? Or rather, can I just store a large json file on ftp and skip using a database?

Thank you so much.

Comment: see the nodejs component is just the server component which interacts with the database to deliver the json. d3/sigma will use the json by doing the ajax, and deliver the graph on a web browser.

Comment: ah, thank you Cyril, I underestimated the size of the json from the database. But can I use Wordpress for this instead of Node.js? Or rather, can I just store a large json file and skip using a database? Probably not a good idea actually... but I would like to keep this in a wordpress

Comment: yep as far as you can get the json from somewhere via ajax to feed into your d3/sigma it will work.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found an existing example similar to what I was looking for:

https://github.com/paulovn/movie-network

http://bl.ocks.org/paulovn/9686202

Woo hoo!!